# How can I run a python script on the command line through the click of an HTML Button?

Tags: javascript, python, html, nginx

I know similar questions have been asked before, and I've done a TON of looking around.

Currently what I am doing is I'm running a python script to create an HTML page (a list of statuses for various applications we run), and then I'm using nginx to serve the content on one of our DNS records.

Since I don't want to constantly run the python application, and create huge logs, I decided the next best option would simply to have an HTML button that the user could press -- triggering the python script to remake the HTML file, and then reload the page.

Before I list what I've tried.. I just want to point out that I cannot use a php solution as there's server issues with running PHP.

First, I tried to run some AJAX POST and that ended up just displaying the script in text for..

```js
function postData(input) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/status.py",
            data: { param: input },
            success: callbackFunc
        });
    }
    
function callbackFunc(response) {
    // do something with the response
    alert(response)
}
    
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    postData("Hello world")
});
```

Then I attempted to create a node application and have come to learn that nodejs runs server side and cannot be called in HTML.. whoops.

Here is a look at the nginx config file

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name mydnsrecord.com;

  charset UTF-8;

  location ~ /.svn/ { deny all; }
  location ~ /.git/ { deny all; }

  location / {
    expires -1;

    alias /path/to/index/;
    index index.html;

    add_header "X-UA-Compatible" "IE=edge";
    add_header "X-Frame-Options" "DENY";

    proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header      Host               $http_host;
  }

  error_page  405     =200 $uri;

}
```

If anyone could point me in the direction or give me some tips on how I can achieve this, that would be amazing.

Thanks.

Comment: Python also runs server side. Is your web server even configured to support running Python scripts? This doesn't sound like an actual programming problem.

Comment: Is flask or django an option?  You sort of need a server of some sort to listen for a button press in order to react to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply link to your python script.

You need to create an API endpoint on your server that will, in turn, run the python script and return a result

Here's a resource that will send you in the right direction:

[how to set up uwsgi and nginx to serve python apps on ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-uwsgi-and-nginx-to-serve-python-apps-on-ubuntu-14-04)

P.S. - Your question is too broad for Stack Overflow

Comment: Hmm, I'll read through that.  I see they also have a version on CentOS which is the distro I'm running.  Thanks for the lead.